# Cannot use string offset as an array (What does it mean?)

Tags: php

The code below is more or less a chunk of my code. The `$servername` and `$monthlyincome` variables are not actually static as shown here but I changed them so I could add less code here.

If I run this code...

```
$servername="Server1";

$months = array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');


for ($i=0;$i<=24;$i++) {
    $new_time = mktime(0,0,0,date("m")+$i,1,date("Y"));
    $months_array[date("Y",$new_time)][date("m",$new_time)] = "x";
}

$overallincome = 0;

foreach ($months_array AS $year=>$month) {
    foreach ($month AS $mon=>$x) {
        $monthlyincome = 3;
        $overallincome += $monthlyincome;

        $$servername[$months[$mon-1]." ".$year]['monthlyincome']=$monthlyincome;
        $$servername[$months[$mon-1]." ".$year]['overallincome']=$overallincome;

    }
}
```

I get this error...

Cannot use string offset as an array in  on line 123

Line 123 is this line... `$$servername[$months[$mon-1]." ".$year]['monthlyincome']=$monthlyincome;`

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have checked other posts on SO with the same error but nothing made sense to me.

Comment: `$$servername[]` might be the problem.  It might be interpreting it at `${$servername[]}` where you want it to interpret as `${$servername}[]`.  Try putting those curly-brackets in there and see if that helps.

Comment: I ran Joe's suggestion and it appears to fix your error.

Comment: It fixed it - Thanks!!! 
I have a similar problem further down the code that is not exactly the same but I'm playing with it now to see if I can figure it out also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting it as an answer, then!

`$$servername[]` seems to be the problem.  It's interpreting it as `${$servername[]}` where you want it to interpret as ${$servername}[].

Try putting those curly-brackets in there and see if that helps.